# Javascript array manipulation / splice(), slice()

Tags: arrays, slice, splice

Javascript beginner.

I apply the split() method to the string, and next apply the splice() array method to the words array, removing two words at array "index 3", "really" and "cool" Since the splice () method returns any deleted words to display these in an alert dialog.

But "index" is unhappy with the code.
the output from script is:

JpowerfulaScript is really cool language

I want the output "javascript is perfect language"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuhSR.png)

Comment: add your code here.

Comment: Show your code here by using the code  tags, not as a image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete solution here

```
    function wrangleArray() {
            var sentence = "JavaScript is really cool language";
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<p>"+ sentence + "</p>";
            var words = sentence.split(" ");
            words.splice(2, 2, "powerful");
            document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = '<p>'+ words.join(" ") + '</p>';

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your code, you have this line:

`var words = sentence.split('');`

Your mistake here as I see it is, you are not splitting by spaces (`' '`) but rather by empty strings.

As can be seen from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4yxj0wh/) splitting by an empty string (the `''` entry in your code), means splitting by every character (since after every character you technically do have an empty string).